# How to make 404 error on homepage?

Tags: .htaccess, server, directory, http-status-code-404, status

I have an empty domain, and would like to return a 404 error when people go to the homepage, or any other URL. Currently, when I go to the domain, I'm being displayed the empty directory.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm being displayed the empty directory.

I assume you mean you are being shown an (Apache generated) index of that directory (which would appear to be empty). This is a "feature" of Apache. To disable directory indexes then include the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file in your document root:

```
Options -Indexes
```

However, this will result in a 403 Forbidden being served when accessing a directory that does not contain a `DirectoryIndex` document (because server-generated directory indexes are "forbidden"). To explicitly return a 404 for all requests, include the following below the above in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

This uses mod_rewrite to instruct Apache to return a 404 status (default error page) for *all* requests.

However, this does assume that you have not defined a custom 404 `ErrorDocument` (otherwise you'll get a 500 error resulting from a rewrite loop).

Comment: That did work, and when I check at https://httpstatus.io/ I get a 403 error. How can I get a 404 though?

Comment: I've updated my answer with regards to returning a 404.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! You are golden!!